# IE8 moves content on mouseover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This is one of the strangest bugs I've ever encountered.

Feel free to check it out [here](http://troubadourtx.com/).

Basically the issue ONLY exists in IE8/Windows (not IE7 or 9 however).  The problem happens when you mouse over the What's Hot image, or any image below that on subsequent rows.  Upon mousing over, it shifts all the content down.  Could this be due to an issue in clearing the floats?  That's my best guess but I can't quite seem to narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: Please post the relevant code within your question and don't make others click and dig for it. `:)`

Comment: There are some JavaScript errors on the page which could be causing the problem, if the hover is a JavaScript event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should fix all the validation errors on your page.  Invalid markup is the #1 cause of weird browser behavior.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftroubadourtx.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

You have 75 errors, and 17 warnings.

Next, you have abotu a zillion stylesheets and selectors..  You might want to prune your css tree and only apply the CSS that's necessary for the page.